# CompletionItemProvider not work in Snippet , Is there a related setting?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

When I select a Snippet and edit it, I am unable to trigger the prompt CompletionItemProvider. Is there a relevant solution
[gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRI56.gif)

````
  return sqlSnippets.map((val) => {
    return {
      label: val.value,
      kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Snippet,
      detail: val.remark,
      documentation: val.description,
      insertText: val.description,
      insertTextRules: monaco.languages.CompletionItemInsertTextRule.InsertAsSnippet,
    }
  })```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can make the CompletionItemProvider to trigger at every key stroke by assigning the triggerCharacters parameter of registerCompletionItemProvider all the key characters you want it to trigger.

Eg:

```js
monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(language, {
                triggerCharacters: [".","a","b"......"z","A","B"...."Z"],
                //rest of the logic
}
```